# aio_write fails on OSX: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: c++, macos, asynchronous, aio

Code for the aio write and read:

```
#include "io_engine.h"

namespace demo {

Status PosixAIOEngine::AsyncWrite(int fd, uint64_t offset, const char* buffer, uint64_t size,
                                  char** cb) {
  // TODO Check io_depth
  requests_.push_back({.aio_req_ = {}, .type_ = kAsyncWrite});
  auto& request = requests_.back();
  memset(&request.aio_req_, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));
  request.aio_req_.aio_offset = (off_t)offset;
  request.aio_req_.aio_buf = (void*)buffer;
  request.aio_req_.aio_nbytes = size;
  request.aio_req_.aio_fildes = fd;

  int ret = aio_write(&request.aio_req_);
  if (ret == -1) {
    auto msg = "aio_write failed, err msg: " + std::string(strerror(errno));
    LOG(ERROR, msg);
    return Status::IOError(msg);
  }

  return Status::OK();
}

Status PosixAIOEngine::AsyncRead(int fd, uint64_t offset, char* buffer, uint64_t size, char** cb) {
  requests_.push_back({.aio_req_ = {}, .type_ = kAsyncRead});
  auto& request = requests_.back();
  memset(&request.aio_req_, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));
  request.aio_req_.aio_offset = (off_t)offset;
  request.aio_req_.aio_buf = (void*)buffer;
  request.aio_req_.aio_nbytes = size;
  request.aio_req_.aio_fildes = fd;

  int ret = aio_read(&request.aio_req_);
  if (ret == -1) {
    LOG(ERROR, "aio_read failed, err: {}, offset: {}, sz: {}", strerror(errno), offset, size);
    requests_.pop_back();
    return Status::IOError("aio read failed!");
  }
  return Status::OK();
}

// TODO Probably we should check the event by their submission order?
uint32_t PosixAIOEngine::Poll() {
  uint32_t cnt = 0;
  auto it = requests_.begin();
  while (it != requests_.end()) {
    auto& req = *it;
    int ret = aio_error(&req.aio_req_);
    if (ret == 0) {
      LOG(INFO, IORequest::GetTypeName(req.type_) +
                    ", callback offset: " + std::to_string(req.aio_req_.aio_offset));
      uint64_t finish_code = aio_return(&req.aio_req_);
      if (finish_code != 0) {
        LOG(ERROR, "return code error : {}, offset: {}", strerror(errno), req.aio_req_.aio_offset);
      }
      it = requests_.erase(it);
      cnt++;
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}

}
```

code of how I test it:

```
#include "io_engine.h"

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <memory>

#include "utils.h"

namespace demo {
class IOEngineTest : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
  std::string file_prefix = "io_engine_test_file_";
  std::string test_file_;
  int write_fd_{};
  int read_fd_{};
  uint64_t file_size_ = 10 << 20;
  std::unique_ptr<IOEngine> io_engine_;

  void SetUp() override {
    test_file_ = CreateRandomFile(file_size_);
    io_engine_ = std::make_unique<PosixAIOEngine>();
    write_fd_ = open(test_file_.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
    if (write_fd_ == -1) {
      LOG(ERROR, "Open writable file failed, error: {}", std::strerror(errno));
      abort();
    }
    read_fd_ = open(test_file_.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    if (read_fd_ == -1) {
      LOG(ERROR, "Open readonly file failed, error: {}", std::strerror(errno));
      abort();
    }
  }

  void TearDown() override {
    int total = FileUtils::DeleteFilesByPrefix(".", file_prefix);
    LOG(INFO, "{} files was deleted", total);
  }

  std::string CreateRandomFile(uint32_t sz) {
    auto filename = FileUtils::GenerateRandomFile(file_prefix, sz);
    filenames_.emplace_back(filename);
    return filename;
  }

 private:
  std::vector<std::string> filenames_;
};

TEST_F(IOEngineTest, MultipleAIOWriteTest) {
  uint64_t page_size = 4UL << 10;
  uint32_t total_requests = 6;

  // Write Request
  for (int i = 0; i < total_requests; ++i) {
    std::string data = std::to_string(i);
    auto s = io_engine_->AsyncWrite(write_fd_, i * page_size, data.c_str(), data.size(), nullptr);
    EXPECT_TRUE(s.ok());
  }

  // POLL result out
  uint32_t cnt = 0;
  while (cnt < total_requests) {
    cnt += io_engine_->Poll();
  }
  EXPECT_EQ(cnt, total_requests);
  EXPECT_EQ(io_engine_->GetInFlightRequests(), 0);

  // Read Request
  char* buf = nullptr;
  posix_memalign((void**)&buf, page_size, total_requests * page_size);
  for (int i = 0; i < total_requests; ++i) {
    auto s = io_engine_->AsyncRead(read_fd_, i * page_size, buf, page_size, nullptr);
    ASSERT_TRUE(s.ok());
  }
  EXPECT_EQ(io_engine_->GetInFlightRequests(), total_requests);

  // POLL result out
  cnt = 0;
  while (cnt < total_requests) {
    cnt += io_engine_->Poll();
  }

  EXPECT_EQ(cnt, total_requests);
  for (int i = 0; i < total_requests; ++i) {
    ASSERT_EQ(buf[i], static_cast<char>(i));
  }
  delete buf;
}
}
```

The io submits are ok, but when I poll the result, the returned finish code is not zero and thus there is an error: "Inappropriate ioctl for device".

Not sure what happens, but IIRC, posix aio library is a user-space aysnc IO engine that should be able to work on any system.

The log message:

```
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.786][132731804][info][utils.h:35] Generate random file, filename: io_engine_test_file_4245618977
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.786][132731804][info][io_engine_test.cc:34] write fd: 4, read fd: 5
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncWrite, callback offset: 4096
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 4096, fd : 4
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncWrite, callback offset: 8192
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 8192, fd : 4
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncWrite, callback offset: 12288
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 12288, fd : 4
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncWrite, callback offset: 0
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 0, fd : 4
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncWrite, callback offset: 16384
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 16384, fd : 4
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncWrite, callback offset: 20480
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 20480, fd : 4
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncRead, callback offset: 4096
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 4096, fd : 5
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncRead, callback offset: 12288
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 12288, fd : 5
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncRead, callback offset: 16384
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 16384, fd : 5
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncRead, callback offset: 20480
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 20480, fd : 5
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncRead, callback offset: 0
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 0, fd : 5
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][info][io_engine.cc:62] kAsyncRead, callback offset: 8192
[2024-03-11 T11:01:36.787][132731804][error][io_engine.cc:66] return code error : Inappropriate ioctl for device, offset: 8192, fd : 5
```

Comment: Can you share the log messages? I feel that there is some problem in while loop inside Poll, this line `it = requests_.erase(it);`.

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks, I just added the log message in the post. I felt there's something wrong with the OSX's aio implementation, but no clue yet.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling ioctl. Not sure if aio does that though. Maybe if you can check running this on some Linux machine. If it works there, then yeah maybe OSX implementation may have some issue.